# FillBetween library sometimes works and sometimes does not

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I have the following MWE using the relatively new `fillbetween` library from `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, decorations.softclip}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalsize]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines*=left, 
            xlabel={x}, ylabel = {y},
            xmin=2,
            xmax=12,
            ymin=-10000,
            ymax = 30000
        ]
        \addplot+[color=green, mark=none, name path=B]  table {dummy.data};
        \path[name path=D] (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:9,0);
        \draw (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:9,0);
        \addplot[color=blue!10] fill between[of=D and B, soft clip={(axis cs:5,-1000) rectangle (axis cs:6,30000)}]; %, soft clip={domain=4.3:9.5}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Now, I want the plot to actually go from `xmin=2` to `xmax=14` or 15.
If I change that in the `axis` options, the plot magically ends up like this...

changed axis code

```
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left, 
    xlabel={x}, ylabel = {y},
    xmin=2,
    xmax=12.5,
    ymin=-10000,
    ymax = 30000
]
```

[image]

The data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9tnjouc9akf2wm/dummy.data

So, what's going on here? :)

Comment: Did you check the warning ?

Comment: @percusse I asked a follow up question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180937/what-is-the-overflow-limit-for-a-named-path-in-tikz-pgfplots. The warning tells me that the path is empty which I could not properly "understand"

Comment: For the record: With the release of PGFPlots v1.16 your example gives the expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 1425 points between `x=0.012` and `x=18.99867` in the dummy.data. It seems that there is a limitation for the number of points used in the plot if the path should be saved.

If I use only every second point (`each nth point=2`) it works for me over the whole range from `xmin=0` to `xmax=20`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, decorations.softclip}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalsize]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left, 
    xlabel={x}, ylabel = {y},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=20,
    ymin=-10000,
    ymax = 30000,
    each nth point=2, % use only every second point
  ]
    \addplot+[color=green, mark=none, name path=B]  table {dummy.data};
    \path[name path=D] (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:9,0);
    \draw (axis cs:4,0) -- (axis cs:9,0);
    \addplot[color=blue!10] fill between[of=D and B,
    soft clip={(axis cs:5,-1000) rectangle (axis cs:6,30000)}];
    %soft clip={domain=4.3:9.5}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned! Is it possible to figure out the exact limitations? Do you think it is a "bug" or should be mentioned somewhere?

Comment: to be honest if there is such an overflow, I would expect an error message or at least a warning somehwere...

Comment: Maybe the limit is 780 points: `x=0` to `x=10.4` works. I do not know if that is a bug. Starting with 0 to 10.41 (781 points) I get a package pgf warning: "fill between skipped: the second input path is empty" In the code the plot (`B`) is the second.

Comment: Yes, well that is however not correct, since it's plotting something. My guess is there's some kind of overflow or some uncaught error. Maybe @ChristianFeuersänger has an idea

Comment: follow up question I asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180937/what-is-the-overflow-limit-for-a-named-path-in-tikz-pgfplots

Answer (score 7):

That is a bug in the intersections library of tikz/pgf as can be seen in the following minimal example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalsize]
        \gdef\softclippath{(axis cs:5,-1000) rectangle (axis cs:6,30000)}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines*=left, 
            xlabel={x}, ylabel = {y},
            xmin=2,
            xmax=12.5,
            ymin=-10000,
            ymax = 30000
        ]
        \addplot+[color=green, mark=none, name path=B]  table {dummy.data};

        \draw[name path=softclippath] \softclippath;
        \node[draw,fill=white,name intersections={of=B and softclippath}] at (rel axis cs:0.5,0.5) 
            {\pgfintersectionsolutions};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The example does not contain any `fillbetween` code, but it does a sub-operation, namely to compute the intersections of the soft clip path with the input path. The `\node` shows the number of intersections. For some reason, that is 0 . If you restore `xmax=12`, you get 2.

I will take care of that bug.

Comment: Hi Christian, I somehow still feel that it has to do something with the sampling number. IF you change the softclip path in your example with `(axis cs:5,-1000) circle (2.3cm)` you get 4. But if you change then the xmax to 15 you get 8. I tend to believe that this because increasing xmax squashes the individual pathlets that makes up the curve and they don't get recognized.

Comment: It surely has, yes. I fear that the intersections library has a couple of related stability issues, and the `fillbetween` library is the first to reveal it. email me if you want to track down the bug! Otherwise I will look into it eventually.

Comment: I will try for sure if time permits me too. My boss is not so enthusiastic about TeX :)

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger is there anything I can do to help? My knowledge of tex internals is still quite limited though.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I fear there is not much to be done. I only mentioned this to percusse because I am aware of his experience and enthusiasm. I also have an interest to fix these bugs.