# What is the overflow limit for a named path in tikz / pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I asked this question [FillBetween library sometimes works and sometimes does not](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180899/fillbetween-library-sometimes-works-and-sometimes-does-not) which led to this answer and discussion https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180926/6908.

There seems to be a limit of data points that can be loaded into a named path before the following warning appears:

> package pgf warning: "fill between skipped: the second input path is
>   empty"

and the result will not be what is wanted.

My question is how big can a named path in `pgfplots` be before such a warning is issued and why does it not tell me that instead of giving an obscure warning that my path is actually empty, which it obviously isn't?

Bug? Feature? Limitation?

Thank you for any clarifications,

T.

P.s.: I tagge tikz and pgf since I don't know where this behavior originates from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no upper limit on the number of path segments: the paths are only limited by CPU and memory resources.

The message indicates a bug in PGF, see [my answer to the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181224/8425).

Comment: How do I go about to get the bug in the "system" and hopefully somebody can fix it one day?

Comment: I already took a note on my personal todo list for pgfplots/pgf (I am developer and maintaince of pgfplots and I can contribute to pgf as well)\. That is sufficient for now.